# Model.save() is bugged?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to pass freecodecamp test which require to submit a name and save it to collection. However, everytime i pressed submit in my form, there is this lengthy warning message in the console :

`(node:20679) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html`

This is my route code :

```
app.post('/api/exercise/new-user/', (req, res) => {
  const {username} = req.body;
  if(username===''){
    res.send('Name must not empty');
  }else{
    const aNewTrainee = new PersonExcer({name:username});
    aNewTrainee.save().then(aTrainee => {
            res.status(200).json(aTrainee);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new todo failed');
        });
  }  
})
```

And since if i tried to query the document collection after save, there is no result, then that can only mean the `save()` call did not work :

```
//This has no result
app.get('/api/exercise/users', (req, res)=>{
  PersonExcer.find(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(docs);
        }
  });
  //This has no result
})
```

Please have a look at the complete code here (edit: link removed).

Comment: I've been try your code and it's working fine. Please update your mongoose to the latests version.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula yes, thank you! Please submit your answer, i will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been try your code and it's working fine, **please update/upgrade** your mongoose to the latest version.

You can use this command line below to check which packages have newer versions available:

```
npm outdate
```

For `upgrade` your mongoose, you can use this command line:

```
npm install mongoose@latest --save
```

For `update`, you can use this command line:

```
npm update mongoose
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe call method is wrong, Check  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
for answers